# Modify multiple images with function

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, function

C gurus!  I need your help!
I have the following block of code that I used to modify an image to make it Oval shaped with a colored border.  It works perfect.  Now, I have 13 other images to make and don't want to have to type this out for each one.  I am sure it would be much easier to store them into an array and pass into a function, but I am tripping up on how exactly to that.

```
CALayer *A = [img1 layer];
[A setMasksToBounds:YES];
[A setCornerRadius:31.0];
[A setBorderWidth:2.5];
[A setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
```

I am hoping someone can teach me and help to turn this into a functional learning experience!
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you add all the images in a `NSArray` for example like that:

```
NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, nil];
```

and then you have just to make a method like

```
-(void)imagesTrasformerByArray:(NSArray *)images{

    for(UIImageView *image in images){

    CALayer *A = [imgage layer];
    [A setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [A setCornerRadius:31.0];
    [A setBorderWidth:2.5];
    [A setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];

    }


}
```

Comment: `UIImage` does not inherit from `UIView`. So this version wouldn't work because you can't access the `layer` of an `UIImage`. The images need to be some kind of view. In this case most likely `UIImageView` --EDIT: Now it's right. Except for "*imgage*"

Comment: where do you see UIImage -.-

Comment: this is PERFECT.  Thank you so much for the fast and accurate response!

Answer (score 1):

> to store them into an array and pass into a function

Yup. That's one option:

```
- (void)makeImageViewsOval:(NSArray*)imgArray {
    for (UIImageView *currentImage in imgArray) {
        CALayer *A = currentImage.layer;
        [A setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [A setCornerRadius:31.0];
        [A setBorderWidth:2.5];
        [A setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
    }
}
```

You could then easily provide your `UIImageView`s like that:

```
[self makeImageViewsOval:@[imgView1, imgView2, imgView3]];
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used the above answer and used your suggestion to call it, as I forgot exactly how that is done.  THANKS.